# Firestore checking if username exists, best model to not query the whole database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm developing and Android app and using Firebase's Firestore. My concern is about creating a username for my user when he is signing up for my app. I know I have to check if the username exists in my database, but what if you have 1 million users or 5. I don't think the results will be fast when you query the whole database. Is querying the whole database the only approach? or maybe creating a collection called usernames with 24 documents inside and for example the first document holds collection of usernames starting with a, then second document holds collection of usernames starting with b, and so on. Need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually one of the [key characteristics of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/#key_capabilities) is exactly that: [the performance of a query is proportional to the size of your result set, not your data set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#querying).

So the query performance that you get for finding 1 document in a collection of 5, 24 or 1 million docments will be exactly the same.

> In Cloud Firestore, you can use queries to retrieve individual,
>   specific documents or to retrieve all the documents in a collection
>   that match your query parameters. Your queries can include multiple,
>   chained filters and combine filtering and sorting. They're also
>   indexed by default, **so query performance is proportional to the size
>   of your result set, not your data set**.

So the answer is that you **should** query your already existing collection of documents and **not** create smaller collection(s) with a subset of documents for the sake of query performance.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer :) but cant get to understand the part that says "query performance is proportional to the size of your result set, not your data set" , does it mean the more documents I want to retrieve the longer it will take? and you have any idea of how the performance is the same when querying collections of different sizes, it blows my mind thanks! (:

Comment: It's neat, isn't it :-) Cloud Firestore is built as the best of two worlds from [Firebase and Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore) so the infrastructure for storing data and creating indexes is to be found amongst those products.